# What is mean yield None (tornado.gen.moment)

Tags: python-3.x, tornado

I need async subprocess lock in my web application.
I writes next code:

```
r = redis.Redis('localhost')
pipe = r.pipeline()
is_locked = False
while not is_locked:
    try:
        pipe.watch(lock_name)
        current_locked = int(pipe.get(lock_name))

        if current_locked == 0:
            pipe.multi()
            pipe.incr(lock_name)
            pipe.execute()
            is_locked = True
        else:
            yield None
    except redis.WatchError:
        yield None
return True
```

In documentation writen that tornado.gen.moment (`yield None` since version 4.5) is a special object which may be yielded to allow the IOLoop to run for one iteration. How it works? Is it next iteration with other Feature object (from other request) or not? Is it correct `yield None` usage?

Comment: Of cource, it in a function decorated tornado.gen.coroutine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gen.moment` is just resolved Future object added to the ioloop with a callback. This allows to run one iteration of ioloop.

The `yield None` is converted to the `gen.moment` using [`convert_yielded`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.convert_yielded) in the coroutine's gen.Runner.

The ioloop (basically `while True`) with each iteration do things like:

1. run callbacks scheduled with ioloop's `add_callback` or `add_callback_from_signal`
2. run callbacks scheduled with ioloop's `add_timeout`
3. poll for fd events (e.g. wait for file descirptor to be ready to write or read). Of course to not block the ioloop the poll has timeout.
4. run handler of ready fds

So getting to the point `yield gen.moment` will allow to do all the things above for one time (one iteration).

As an example let's schedule async task - httpclient fetch that requires running ioloop to be finished. On the other hand there will be also blocking function (`time.sleep`).

```
import time
from tornado import gen
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient


@gen.coroutine
def fetch_task():
    client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    yield client.fetch('http://google.com')
    print('fetch_task finished')


@gen.coroutine
def blocking():
    start_time = time.time()
    counter = 1 
    while True:
        time.sleep(5)
        print('blocking for %f' % (time.time() - start_time))
        yield gen.moment
        print('gen.moment counter %d' % counter)
        counter += 1


@gen.coroutine
def main():
    fetch_task()
    yield blocking()


IOLoop.instance().run_sync(main)
```

Observation:

- without a `yield gen.moment`, the `fetch_task` won't be finished
- increase/decrease value of `time.sleep` does not affect the number of required iteration of a ioloop for the `fetch_task` to be completed. This means also that a `AsyncHTTPClient.fetch` is `N + 1` (gen.moments + the task schedule) interactions with ioloop (handling callbacks, polling fd, handling events).
- `gen.moment` does not always mean, the other tasks will be finished, rather they get opportunity to be one step closer to completeness.